# How to get 'dy' of baseline in svg text?

Tags: text, svg, baseline

For svg text elements coordinates are apply to the left bottom corner of baseline.

[image: my example with text]

I have a text whose width and height are known, thus I can set 
`row.height = 2 * text.height`
Then I want to place 2 text element in this row, one above the other, and I set text.y coordinate to `coordinate of top left corner of row + text.heigh * 2`. 
To set the bottom line of text right above row border, but this coordinate apply to baseline thus text little lowered. You can see it on the picture.

So, how to know the baseline offset, to set text coordinate like

`y = top left corner of row + height of text - baseline offset`
?

My example on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6r14wnsw/)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to do this in SVG.  You can get the bounding box of a text element and even the bounding box of an individual character. Unfortunately, the bounding box you get is the "em box" (the blue box in your screenshow) and not the actual bounds of the glyph(s).

Answer (score 1):

@paul-lebeau your answer with mention about em box size gave me the idea how to calculate baseline offset. We have coordinate of top left corner of em box and it height and coordinate of text element baseline. So

`embox.y + embox.heigh - text_baseline.y == baseline_offset`

thus we can set text coordinate like `y = row.height - baseline_offset`.
http://jsfiddle.net/6r14wnsw/1/

And I find more simple receipt http://jsfiddle.net/tpafwLmm/1/  set text attribute `dominant-baseline="text-after-edge"` will shift baseline to the bottom edge of embox, `text-before-edge` - top edge of embox.